# How to access native SQLite database with an application

Tags: iphone, html, sqlite, ios5

I want to make an application for iphone, ipad, and android using HTML 5.

This application will create a SQLite database or place a prefilled SQLite database file when it is installed on ipad/iphone/android.

I want to keep it in a folder where my application is installed.

eg

ApplicationName- Files (where I have all the files for the application)

ApplicationName- DB    (where I will have my sqllite database)

I want to connect to SQLiteDB using javascript.

Can I access the db at a particular location from my application using Javascript or jquery.

Can you suggest me some way I can get into this.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look at Apache Cordova (old Phonegap) to see how they handle things or use they own solution for this kind of thing.

But if you really want to walk alone, you need to build 2 sets of frameworks to call native code, or use web sql database(inactive) or something similar.

iOS
http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

Android
http://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/2012/04/30/building-android-javajavascript-bridges/